# Unable to overload + operator to add 2 objects

Tags: c++, class, debugging, operator-overloading

I have a class employee

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class employee
{
    public:

            double operator + (employee);
            employee operator + (employee);
            employee(int);
            double getSalary();

    private:

           double salary;

};

int main()
{  
  employee A(400);
  employee B(800);

  cout<<A+B;

  employee C = A+B; //overload + operator to add 2 object together

  cout<<C.getSalary();

}

employee::employee(int salary)
{
    this->salary = salary;
}


double employee::operator + (employee e)
{
    double total;

    total = e.salary + this->salary;

    return total;    
}

employee employee::operator + (employee e)
{

    double total;

    total= this->salary + e.salary;

    employee c(total);

    return c;


}

double employee::getSalary()
{
    return this->salary;
}
```

I am trying to overload the + operator to work with 2 employee objects so i can add them together but i am getting a compiler error

> employee operator + (employee) cannot be overloaded;

I dont understand why and how do i go about overloading the + operator to add 2 objects of the same class

Comment: You can't overload on return type.

Answer (score 2):

You have two operators `+` with different return types but the same arguments, so the compiler can't tell which one to use. So for this example and because you can't "add" two employees i only used one operator:

```
class employee
{
    public:
            //you only need one + operator
            double operator + (const employee & e)const;
            //constructor is taking a double so that your code works.
            employee(double);
    private:
           double salary;
};

double operator + (const employee & e)const
{
    return salary + e.salaty;    
}
employee::employee(double s)
    :salary(s)
{
}
```

The rest of the code is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You cant overload operator on the basis of return type..

Beside this there is one more problem in your code. 
Your need to overload << operator which takes a right-hand operand of type 'employee'